# Jenkins: How to mark successfully running job as "Success" to circumvent hanging terminal and continue pipeline?

Tags: java, spring, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm new to Jenkins and I'm trying to build a Pipeline from small jobs.

I have 5 modules that I manually launch one after another, in a synchronous manner.

I wanted to build jenkins pipeline for those 5 modules, so that I wont have to do all the stuff manually over and over again.

I have written a pipeline script for the first module, which:

- fetches the repository,
- does `mvn clean install`
- does `mvn package`
- deploys module using `java -jar ./target/*.jar`.

I am planning to write a pipeline script for every module in this fashion, and then I plan to tie them together, one after another.

However, this pipeline script gets stuck at "Deploy" phase, because java -jar successfully deploys the module. (I deploy a server, which hangs I/O for logging, nothing interactive).

I thought deploying the module using `nohup` or detached process using `&`, however in that case Jenkins will report Success even if my server throws an exception and exits.

I thought that if I can find a way to mark this job as SUCCESS, then I can proceed to next module, and so on.

Those are the logs that hangs my jenkins pipeline:

> 10-07-2018 11:20:44.179 [35m[main][0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start
>   - Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) 10-07-2018 11:20:44.180 [35m[main][0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m
>   org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.onApplicationEvent
>   - Updating port to 8081

It means server is successfully running. Nothing is wrong. I'm looking for a way to deploy all my modules one after another. I'm new to jenkins, so I might be asking a stupid question, please feel free to enlighten me with potentionally other ways to make it work.

Thank you for your efforts :)

Comment: If I understand your approach correctly, you are not really deploying the module but you execute it in the Jenkins process. This will run your module on the build server.
That is not, for what Jenkins is made. If you use it this way, you will start a new instance of your module, every time the pipeline runs.
Normally, depending on the type of your module, you would deploy it to an application server or within a container or something like that.

Can you please elaborate, what you want to achieve?

Comment: It seems, that you want to run an application in a Tomcat? Normally, the Tomcat should always run somewhere on a server and you just deploy the application war file to that server. You can do this via the Tomcat API. Maybe you want to read http://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-deploy-war